# How sizeof a not-polymorphic C++ class can be larger than the summed sizeof of its members?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sizeof

In the following example struct `E` inherits structs `C` and `D` and has no other data members:

```
struct A{};
struct B{};
struct C : A, B {};
struct D : A, B {};
struct E : C, D {};

int main() {
    static_assert(sizeof(C) == 1);
    static_assert(sizeof(D) == 1);
    //static_assert(sizeof(E) == 2); // in Clang and GCC
    static_assert(sizeof(E) == 3); //in MSVC
}
```

In all compilers I have tested, `sizeof(C)==1` and `sizeof(D)==1`, and only in MSVC `sizeof(E)==3` so more than the summed size of its parents/members, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/aEK7rjKcW

Actually I expected to find `sizeof(E) <= sizeof(C)+sizeof(D)` (less in case empty base optimization). And there is hardly any padding here, otherwise `sizeof(E)` would be 2 or 4.

What is the purpose of extra space (`sizeof(E)-sizeof(C)-sizeof(D) == 1`) in `E`?

Comment: Due to [EBO](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo) I am actually surprised by the output from MSVC

Comment: You created a "diamond inheritance" shape. I.e. the base classes A and B exist twice in E. Unless you do virtual inheritance, which you did not. The interesting question now, is, in those compilations, where `sizeof(E) == 1`, how can they achieve, that `E e; assert(static_cast<A*>(static_cast<C*>(&e)) !=static_cast<A*>(static_cast<D*>(&e)));` ?

Comment: @BitTickler: I checked the offsets -- they put `D` at offset 1. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8r9384fK8

Comment: Okay - maybe my assert was not the sharpest assert on the block... but you have 2*A and 2* B in E. So you should be able to obtain 4 different addresses for them, yes?

Comment: @BitTickler: `A` and `B` are allowed to have the same address. It's different `A`s and different `B`s that are not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it can be larger than the sum of sub-objects due to padding and alignment. However, you're probably aware of that, and that's not what you are asking.

To determine the layout in your case, you can print the offsets of all the sub-objects (and the sizes of their types) using the following code:

```
static E x;
int main() {
    E *e = &x;
    C *c = e;
    D *d = e;
    A *ca = c, *da = d;
    B *cb = c, *db = d;
#define OFF(p) printf(#p " %d %d\n",  (int)((char*)p - (char*)e), (int)sizeof(*p))
    OFF(e);
    OFF(c);
    OFF(ca);
    OFF(cb);
    OFF(d);
    OFF(da);
    OFF(db);
}
```

The output for gcc/clang is:

```
e 0 2
c 0 1
ca 0 1
cb 0 1
d 1 1
da 1 1
db 1 1
```

The output for MSVC is:

```
e 0 3
c 0 1
ca 0 1
cb 1 1
d 2 1
da 2 1
db 3 1
```

This indicates that the way MSVC implements EBO is different from other compilers. In particular, instead of placing `A` and `B` at the same address within `C`, and at the same address within `D` (like other compilers do), it put them at different offsets. Then, even though `sizeof(C) == 1`, it allocates the full two bytes for it when it is a sub-object. This is most likely done so to avoid `cb` aliasing some other `B` from another sub-object, even though it wouldn't be a problem in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks. Is it allowed by the standard that at the same time `sizeof(C)==1` and one of `C` fields `cb` has displacement 1?

Comment: @Fedor I do not know; but I can see how it can cause problems if you try to `memcpy` the sub-object.